# JSF: Is there a way to bind method to h:outputLink?

Tags: jsf

I am working on something like this:

A JSF template has a side-navigation bar which contains links(either anchor or h:outputLink), and there are cases where two options lead to the same link(page), but with a different value in view parameter, and thus rendering different data being displayed on the page.

Is there a way to do this? Using commandLink or commandButton does not seem like an option to me since it will mess up the styling.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `f:outputLink` doesn't exist, you probably mean `h:outputLink`

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie my bad, just corrected it.

Comment: No one are dead, only pointing small errors to make everything better! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An output link is just a normal HTML link, so a conventional way to do this is with a query parameter, e.g. `/contentarea.xhtml?myparam=value`.

I don't think you should bind a method to the output link. That would involve a Javascript onclick handler (`commandLink`), and I don't think that's necessary here. That said, I'm surprised you say `commandLink` messes with the styling, as it renders a normal HTML link.

#### See also

- http://incepttechnologies.blogspot.ca/p/view-parameters-in-jsf-20.html (see the first technique using `f:viewParam`)
- http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-link-commandlink-and-outputlink-example/

Comment: I think the reason commandLink messes with the styling is because it has to be put inside a form and somehow it is the form that ruins the styling on the page. I was asking a general question because I knew there is a method to invoke the setter method in the backing bean yet I was not sure what it is. This way I think it is invoking the setter and it sets the field in my backing bean. Thanks again. :)